# ASP.net losing data on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to override the  SaveViewState() function in asp.net in order to save some data so I do not lose it on the postback.
Is there a way to store the command argument of the dynamic linkbutton event that was most recently clicked? So when I do the postback, I can create a new set of linkbuttons.

Ie  I dynamically created a set of linkbuttons each with a CommandArgument
I want to store that command argument before the postback.
IF this is too confusing I apologize

Thank you for any help or resources to look at!
Jason

Comment: store in a static variable or a Session variable would be my first choice(s)

Comment: This is what the ViewState is for, then you do not burden your server with the data. Alternatively you can use Session and configure it to use Sql Server (for farm deployments) or InProc for single web server. The benefit of Session is that data persists between page calls without having to write any extra code. Downside is data is persisted on the server and not the client like it is with ViewState.